# asp.net MVC ajax method not called in proper order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an asp.net application and I want to show login popup if user is not authenticated and if user is authenticated then memberarea popup on same page.

I have this controller action method

```
 [ActionName("151LoginAPI")]
        public ActionResult NewCallRecording(string ID, string PSSWD, string ACCID, string PASSWDINT)
        {
....
....
...

return view();
}
```

in 151API view I have done this in document.ready function

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/recording/verifyUser",
                data: {
                    ID: $("#ID").val(),
                    PSSWD: $("#PSSWD").val(),
                    ACCID: $("#ACCID").val(),
                    PASSWDINT: $("#PASSWDINT").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "success") {

                        jQuery('#dialog-AddCallRecording').dialog({ closeOnEscape: false });


                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
                        $("#dialog-AddCallRecording").dialog({ dialogClass: 'transparent', modal: true });
                        $("#dialog-AddCallRecording").dialog("open");                     

                    }
                    else {
                        jQuery("#dialog-user-login").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
                        jQuery("#dialog-user-login").dialog("open");
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have defined verifyuser and it is authenticating and showing proper popup.

It is working fine but problem is when i set breakpoints. I see that NewCallRecording is always hit. and verifyuser is hit after that. I want to make it so that verifyuser is checked first and then NewCallRecording actionmethod is hit when user opens /NewCallRecording page

Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

VerifyUser call is ajax, and NewCallRecording is a controller action. If the action is called directly, it will be executed before the Ajax call, as DOM is loaded by the actionresult, which in this case is NewCallRedording..

In this case, I think you would need to do server side validation as well, and redirect user to login page if the user isn't verified.

Comment: Should i remove ajax call in that case ? Also, If I make NewCallRecording actionmethod just a dummy action method for GEt operation and create another one for POST ? but I need GEt i think ... I am really confused

Comment: Ajax is useful if you want to verify the user after page load, on any other call-to-action. You ccould make dummy action call, do ajax validation and then call actual action, but this seems a bit convoluted. Consider decorating your action with an attribute, which can be an action filter, that verifies user before the action execution.